# jQuery - Prevent jump but follow hashed link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    $( '.prevent-default' ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });    
});
```

I give hashed anchors the class `.prevent-default` to stop the window from jumping when the link is clicked. Unfortunately, `event.preventDefault();` also stops the browser from following the link.

**How can I only stop the window from jumping but follow the link?**

I already tried `window.location.href = jQuery( this ).attr('href');` but that didn't work at all - the window jumped.

Comment: What is the `href` value of the link?

Comment: If the link is a hashed version of the current page then what behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: The purpose of the 'hashed link' is to make the page jump - it's a link to a bookmark in the page. What behaviour are you expecting it to have?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using it for a tabbed navigation that can be accessed through hashlinks like `#link1` to open the first tab. So the link should be followed but without the jump to the top.

Comment: But the point of a haslink ***is*** the jump. Do you mean that you'd like it to scroll gradually in to view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `display:fixed` DIV-element at click-time as first dom-node in body with your anchor as `id`.

If you use id's for jumping, you need to have the same id twice for a short time. Take care that this dynamic div will be deleted after jump.

Answer (score 0):

You can try animate with this:

```
$( '.prevent-default' ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('#'+this.href).position().top});
});
```